# Why does spring-boot-data-jdbc Query Methods require No Args Constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

It seems to me that all Query methods over an entity, using the spring-boot-data-jdbc, require to have a No-Args Constructor?
Is there a reason why?
Here is a simple example which gives this exception. Using H2 database

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate [com.example.relationaldataaccess.Person]: No
> default constructor found; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
> com.example.relationaldataaccess.Person.()

Typically Person entity -

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Person {
    

    @Id
    private long id;
    private  String firstName;
    private  String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

And then the repository

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>{

    @Query("select * from person where first_name= :firstName")
    List<Person> findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);

}
```

Here is the schema

```
create table person (
                        id integer identity not null primary key,
                        first_name varchar(30),
                        last_name varchar(30)
);
```

And the Main App

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repository;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        Person person = new Person("John", "Doe");
        repository.save(person);
        System.out.println("FIND BY FIRST_NAME ----->> "+ repository.findByFirstName("John"));
    }
}
```

The application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:persondb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.data=INFO
```

Below is the stack trace of the app-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.relationaldataaccess.Application.main(Application.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate com.example.relationaldataaccess.Person using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments 
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:65) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.BasicRelationalConverter.createInstance(BasicRelationalConverter.java:147) ~[spring-data-relational-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.createInstanceInternal(BasicJdbcConverter.java:527) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.mapRow(BasicJdbcConverter.java:387) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter.mapRow(BasicJdbcConverter.java:323) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.EntityRowMapper.mapRow(EntityRowMapper.java:67) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcQueryLookupStrategy$PostProcessingRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcQueryLookupStrategy.java:152) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:679) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:694) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:176) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.AbstractJdbcQuery.lambda$getQueryExecution$2(AbstractJdbcQuery.java:127) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.StringBasedJdbcQuery.execute(StringBasedJdbcQuery.java:85) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.findByFirstName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.relationaldataaccess.Application.run(Application.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.relationaldataaccess.Person]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.relationaldataaccess.Person.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:146) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:62) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.relationaldataaccess.Person.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:139) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted

2020-09-23 19:31:04.053  INFO 29948 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-09-23 19:31:04.059  INFO 29948 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What happens if you add `@ConstructorProperties({"firstName", "lastName"})` to the constructor, or when you compile using the `-parameters` flag?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is misleadng.
Spring Data JDBC does not require a No-Args-Constructor, but it needs a way to set all the attributes and does not access private fields.
They are private after all and should therefore only be accessed by the class owning them.
This requirement is not satisfied by your `id` field.

Doing one of the following should resolve the issue:

- make the `id` field at least package private, i.e. no modifier
- add a setter for the `id` field. At least again package private
- add `id` to the arguments of the constructor.
- add a constructor with all three fields as arguments. You might have to add `@PersistenceConstructor` to that constructor.